# Django Inconsistent Test after Patch

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-testing

I get inconsistencies when getting results after `patch`. I am trying to compare the results after I patch. I want to store data in a variable before it is get deleted when I patch. When I try to print a data after it is patched, it gets the new and different result. Below, I want to store the old dogs in `old`. However after patch, it gets renewed to new values like `new`. My patch serializer deletes the old record when patching.

```
#models.py
class Owner(models.Model):
    owner = models.CharField()

class Dog(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Owner,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField()

#test.py
class Update(APITestCase):
    def test_update_dog(self):
        old = Dog.objects.filter(owner=1).order_by('id')
        print(old) # <QuerySet [<Dog: Ben>, <Dog: Phoebe>]>

        data = {
            'dogs': [
                {'name': 'Ryan'},
                {'name': 'Louis'}
            ]
        }

        response = self.client.post(
            '/admin/login/', {'username': 'admin', 'password': 'password123'})

        response = self.client.patch('/app/dogs/1/',
                                     data=data,
                                     format='json')

        new = Dog.objects.filter(owner=1).order_by('id')
        print(new) # <QuerySet [<Dog: Ryan>, <Dog: Louis>]>
        print(old) # <QuerySet [<Dog: Ryan>, <Dog: Louis>]>

        self.assertNotEqual(old[0].name, new[0].name)
        self.assertNotEqual(old[1].name, new[1].name)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that querysets in Django are [lazy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy). When you store the old result in variable it doesn't mean that any DB activity was actually performed. You may just store attribute value and make check kind like this:

```
old = Dog.objects.filter(owner=1).order_by('id').values('id', 'name')
...
self.assertNotEqual(old, new.values('id', 'name'))
```